# How can I change the subject on email sent from chatter?

Tags: email, case

We are using the 'Send email' from the chatter feed within our case object
[image]

Is it possible that when creating a new email, the subject will contain the case id ?
couldn't locate where to do this.
[image]

So in this example subject would say: test automation : 0001123

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps:-

1. Write a trigger on Email Message
2. Event should be before Insert
3. Check if Email Subject is in specific format or not
4. Throw the error if not
5. If you don't want to throw the error, you concat the case reference in the subject

Another way is prepopulating it in subject when you are sending it from action using predefined values, but it do not restrict the users from removing it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an email template, in which you can use merge fields to include information from the Case (like the Case Number in the Subject).

Then in the Case when you send an email, just select your template and the subject will be automatically populated with what you defined in the template.

Documentation link : [create email template](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_create_a_template.htm&type=5)